# redirect with mask on AWS S3, cloudfront and route53

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, mask, amazon-route53

I have an example.com domain name and I would like to redirect to subdomain.otherexample.com but I don't like that when the redirection occurs the old URL is showing subdomain.otherexample.com how could I do that?
I am actually using S3 and Cloudfront.

Actually, from cloudfront redirect to S3 and a record type A use an alias to redirect to cloudfront

Comment: could you please provide some more details with respect to you website flow?

Answer (score 0):

I am using S3 to redirect to the web that I want to show, in static web hosting, my service provider gives me the following sub.example.com url and additional shows two NS,
ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com.

S3> in the redirection I place sub.example.com and the http protocol since it does not use https.

Route53> add two A records with Alias
1. www.mydomain.com to s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
2. mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com

www.mydomain.com redirects but does not hide sub.example.com and mydomain.com shows 404 error

```
    Code: NoSuchBucket
    Message: The specified bucket does not exist
    BucketName: mydomain.com
    RequestId: DA0B8E051C8F5842
    HostId: RBiqPpf6 / l + i0GlT4ZSEPizxT + 3oEr4d1ZoxtyxE3Yhyk / hXEyYDU3 / 
    ItZe9NsUKkTtmc6wL + g8 =
```

Thanks for answering